# How to do handle pagination with Extension method?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, pagination

I have next Extension method for pagination which work with News Api

```
        fun pagination(viewModel: EverythingViewModel): RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
        return object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        if (dy > 0) {
            val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
            val firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
            val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.childCount
            val totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount
            if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount) {
                viewModel.page++
                viewModel.getEverything()
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And this method is called like this

```
everythingRecycler.addOnScrollListener(pagination(viewModel))
```

But this code works crookedly and also I have three fragment and how I need to change this Extension method that I can use this method for three fragment and with different viewModel

Comment: What does `works crookedly` mean?

Comment: It mean that code work malfunctioning or don't work correctly

Answer (score 0):

The logic is: You need to set a `listener` to get the `last visible item` from respective `LayoutManager` and if user reached to the `last item` of your provied list, then make `API/SDK` calls to load more data.

I have already developed a library called `LazyLoadingRecyclerView` for `LayLoading`/`Pagination`/`InfiniteScrolling`

Github Link: https://github.com/rommansabbir/LazyLoadingRecyclerView/

Comment: How I call api request in Extension file?

Comment: I want to make pagination work one call at a time in a fragment

Comment: You have to call API request from the Listener `loadMore()` function. Yes, you can limit the call, store a counter to handle one time API call only.

Comment: I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Check the documentation.